# Website displays only IIS splash screen after change of application pool

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I develop website based on classic ASP and IIS7. Today I've changed application pool and the website's stopped working immediately. The only thing I can see now is the IIS7 splash(logo) screen on homepage.
The new app pool has exactly the same runtime version as the previous one(.NET Framework 2.0) and the only difference is the pool's Identity User. 
I've noticed too that when I try to access the URL

> mywebsite.com/default.asp

there's

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

and then Physical Path

> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\defalt.asp

, although there's different path set for this website in IIS Manager.

Comment: Is it Asp? or AspX?

Comment: All pages are with .asp extensions here so Asp I guess

Answer (score 1):

In the Advanced Settings of the pool, change the `Managed Pipeline Mode` from `Integrated` to `Classic`:

[image]

You can also check this page: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753918(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, no changes. I noticed the pool that was working correctly earlier is set on Integrated too.